# Handling a blank cell which is rendering a true, which is 1, versus no value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I used an IF function to determine if a delivery is on time.  True=1, false = 0, but if the determining date cell is blank, it renders a 1 in the count cell resulting in a false count. I want to write a formula like countblank, or if blank to go with what is there to count blank cells as zero. Thanks!

From the OP's Comments:

The formula is,

```
=IF(G9<F9+8, 1, 0)
```

1 or 0 posts in H9 so I can sum the totals. so everything works if there is a date in G9, but if G9 is blank, it counts as true posting a 1. I suppose if the cell is blank it actually is less than F9+8, but I need a blank to render a 0 in H9.

Comment: Sorry my picture didn't post. Anyway the formula is

Comment: the formula is =IF(G9<F9+8, 1, 0).  1 or 0 posts in H9 so I can sum the totals.  so everything works if there is a date in G9, but if G9 is blank, it counts as true posting a 1.  I suppose if the cell is blank it actually is less than F9+8, but I need a blank to render a 0 in H9.

Answer (score 1):

To rectify your formula, add an [AND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5F19B2E8-E1DF-4408-897A-CE285A19E9D9) that will discard blank cells from consideration.

```
=IF(AND(G9<F9+8, G9<>""), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Hello Jeeped.  Thank you very much for your solution.  It worked very well.  I really appreciate it.